# Web scraping the table from the website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to grab and parse all table data from the web https://html5test.com/. 
so, I wrote the following code.But its not showing any data. I looked over the question answer but can't figure out the problem.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re


url='https://html5test.com/'
data=urlopen(url)

parse=BeautifulSoup(data).findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'resultsTable detailsTable'})
```

Comment: table data is in `post` request

Comment: Do you have code how to parse the complete table data? I am new in webscraping by using python and beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the source code (view-source:https://html5test.com/ in Chrome), I don't actually find the 'resultsTable` class. It looks like this is generated dynamically using JavaScript. You need a scraper which renders JavaScript, for example, Scrapy with Splash (cf. https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/).

Comment: I can see the class "resultsTable detailsTable" by using chrome developer tools.

Comment: @jisan No, don't rely on developer tools, as it shows data after page load, always check from `view source code` to authenticate